# Problem formula with \usepackage{marvosym} \usepackage{tikzsymbols} \usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}

Tags: fonts, amsmath, tikz-styles

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\section{Prove}
\( x \in A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)\) 
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

and the output is:
[image]

but if I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\section{Prove}
\( x \in A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)\) 
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

the output is:
[image]

Why Are outputs different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case you get the symbols from `MnSymbol`

Comment: thanks for answer... but How Can I do to have first case in second case with package MnSymbol??

Comment: If you do not want the MnSymbols then do not load that package!

Comment: mmm okok, but after I need of the smiles \Coffeecup e \blacksmiley{} in first version of Prove.. Is it impossible?

Comment: `\Coffecup is from `tikzsymbols` or `marvosym` and `blacksmiley` from `wasysym`. No need fpr package `MnSymbol`

Comment: ah... I don't know it! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

The second version takes the `\in` and `\subseteq` symbols from `MnSymbol` since you loaded it last. The first version uses `LMathSymbols` as defined by the `lmodern` package.

Comment: But why do you load MnSymbol? These fonts are designed to go well with Minion Pro, they cerainly math Latin Modern. It might only be conceivable to use *some* symbols fom MnSymbol that are not available otherwise.